# Parse UNIX-time from char[]

Tags: time, mkr1000, web-service

I want to parse a large number to sync time on my arduino. For this i send it a string with the current time in Unix time format wich looks somethink like this:

> 1535441277

For this I just call a php script wich echos the `time()` function.

But with  `string.toInt()`I'm unable to parse it. I suppose the number is too large for an int or a long. But I can't put it directly into the `setEpoch()` method from the RTCzero libary because it accepts as input datatype only `uint32_t`. So how can I parse large numbers on a system where double isn't implemented. And I don't just try to parse the entire HTTP-Response. I iterate thru the response and at the relevant line I write all the chars into a char-Array. I also have removed the \r and \n chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 32 bit systems, `uint32_t` is usually the same as `unsigned int` and `unsigned long`. You should be able to parse the number using [`strtoul()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/), which is quite standard and returns an `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response. I also found another solution: Before echoing the time remove a large chuck of the time by just removing the current timestamp on the server-side. Later on I add the exact same amount when using the `setEpoch()` function. I know that's not very elegant but it works for me.

Comment: How do you share the time base (that large chunk) between the Arduino and the PC?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, subtract epoch time of the first second of this year

Comment: So you already have current time set on both Arduino and the PC?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, read the question. he gets the time with HTTP GET request to his service on the server

Comment: @Juraj I totally don't see that in the question.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, It is expert's translation of " I just call a php script wich echos the time() function."

Comment: @Juraj But that's the string he's having a hard time parsing in the first place, isn't it? Also, GET request goes from Arduino to the server, and the output of `time` goes the other way around.